# Is SSL necessary on localhost?

Tags: security, iis, networking, https

We have a web application which will use self signed certificates, and after installing it on the server, the browser will open at "https://localhost" (no, for argument's sake, I will state that we cannot use the actual machine name).
This will generate a browser error, because "localhost" is not the certificate's domain.

An option, is to expose the application on HTTP *only* on the loopback (localhost).

Our application should be encrypted whenever it is passing outside of the server, so - the question..

> Are there any security concerns around allowing HTTP access to our
>   application on localhost (and only on localhost)? Does this expose the
>   application to snooping from outside of the computer?

One can assume that if someone was able to access the machine's local user sessions, then we have bigger worries, and the lack of HTTP would hence be insignificant.

Answer (score 10):

There could be other process sniffing the loopback interface. It could be a service running in you PC, sniffing and sending data outside to a remote server.

You can still use https with a domain name, like https://www.myowndomain.com and in the hosts file you map this domain to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Thanks rodolk. We can assume that if malicious software has obtained access to the box, the battle is lost anyway. My concern really is - can off-box software snoop the loopback? My research thus far has indicated not.

Comment: @Adam, you are right. The only way is to get access to to the server as administrator or root, not a process from other PC/device.